# Choose any (#00000000 - #FFFFFFFF) widget background color in configuration activity

Tags: android

Why is there no

```
public RemoteViews.setDrawable(int viewId, String methodName, Drawable value)
```

?

Can I extend `RemoteViews` and make my own?

**My Actual Question:** Is there *ANY* way to let the user pick the background color of a widget (aside from a limited selection of `R.drawable.*` or similar)?

I just want a text view with a solid color (user-defined #00000000 - #FFFFFFFF) behind it.  I don't want 16^8 = 4,294,967,296 (4.3 Billion with a "B") files in my drawable folder.  I can't find a way to accomplish this task that I assumed would be trivial.  Please tell me I'm missing something obvious...

Answer (score 0):

**[`setImageViewBitmap (int viewId, Bitmap bitmap)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setImageViewBitmap%28int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29)**

so you convert your preferred Color to a Bitmap. for eg

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(Color.RED);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
//now your bitmap is ready 
RemoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ids,bitmap);
```

*i have not tested this*

Hope it helps